# Laravel 5.7 500 error on PHP 7.2 enviroment

Tags: php, laravel

I have made an script using Laravel which runs smoothly on an WAMPP server with PHP 7.2. Recently, I tried to go live, but my server runs into **500 Error**. My Server is running PHP 7.2 and matches the requirements listed in laravel documentation.

Now comes the real problem - There's nothing in the logs. As per my knowledge, Laravel logs errors into storage/logs but it's just blank.

What could be the reason behind it?

I am running on an Apache Server with cpanel and whm.

Comment: Show us the full error please.

Comment: Hi Pratik and welcome to Stackoverflow! The thing with error 500 is, that you can lookup the problem in the log files. Everything else is just guessing. Developers don't play guessing games when they know the error is written in a log file!

Comment: You'll have to check your apache logs if nothing is in `storage/logs/`

Comment: First look should be in the PHP log, not in Laravel or Apache log.

Comment: @DanFromGermany  As I said above, The error log is blank, There is no apache log

Comment: Then you have to enable the logging. It's still a guessing game buddy.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have it enabled :-)

Comment: Ok what is the error then?

Comment: @PratikPatil there must be an apache log. By default it would be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web server has writing privileges to the `/storage` folder and all its sub-folders. I always have this problem when creating a new application.

Comment: Cross checked, 0755 Permission is set :-)

Comment: @PratikPatil with what owner/group?